# contribute and contribute to

Tags: word-usage

I understand that sentence (1) is correct but what is wrong with sentence (2)

1)The trading segment contributes 10% of the company total revenue
2)The trading segment contributes **to** 10% of the company total revenue

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The trading segment contributes 10% of the company total revenue

This sentence means that **10% company total revenue** = **Trading segment** or in other word 10% of company total revenue is because of the trading segment.

> The trading segment contributes to 10% of the total company revenue

Say company's total revenue is 100. Out of 100, consider the segment 10. Call it Name A. And trading company contributes something to that Name A.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on the explanation of sentence 2.  Thanks

Comment: Actually in this case they both are almost similar in meaning, with a subtle difference. And that I tried to capture in my answer above. General form is ***"contribute something to something else"***

Comment: @Pupu Thinking of it like this might help. In "... contributes X", X is "what is contributed". In "... contributed to X", X is the "target of the contribution" (i.e. "to where or to whom the contribution goes").